# Relative path for img src

Tags: 2013, css, html

I'm trying to get my relative path for my image, as this site will be re-used on different sites on the site collection.

and the sharepoint url would been this sitecollection.sharepoint.com/topsite/subsite.
Thats the reason why I can't use the full URL. as the subsite name would be different every time. But the image will always be in the same document library on the subsite.

```
<img src="./Shared%20Documents/enddate.png" />
```

tl;dr need the relative url path for the image.

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="/Shared%20Documents/enddate.png" />`?

Comment: <img src="../SiteAssets/enddate.png"> did actually work.
But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as

```
<img src='<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$SPUrl:~site/Shared%20Documents/enddate.png%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>' alt="" />
```